# A reference for Bernstein's approach to KL conjectures

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, d-modules, perverse-sheaves, kazhdan-lusztig

The exposition in the famous J. Bernstein's lecture notes on D-modules is rather sketchy.

Fortunately, there are many other sources for the information from this text (like Hotta's excellent "D-modules, perverse sheaves, ..." or notes by Etingof, Braverman and others). But it seems that all of them cover only the first five chapters of Bernstein's book: I can't find any place where the material of the crucial one, the 6th, would be written carefully enough.

For example, Hotta's approach is somewhat different: he uses techniques of Hodge D-modules instead of the original BB argument. The same problem is with notes by Yi Sun (highly based on the previous source) who uses Bott-Samelson resolutions of the Schubert varieties. And Etingof (et al.) doesn't mention KL at all.

So my question is: is there any source where the original BB proof of the KL conjectures is written rather carefully?